# Keep getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

That's the response for `Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass($this));`

```
Class [ class Users extends Crud ] { 
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 5-76 
- Constants [0] { 
} 

- Static properties [0] { 
} 

- Static methods [0] {
} 

- Properties [7] {
    Property [ protected $table ]
    Property [ private $username ]
    Property [ private $email ]
    Property [ private $password ]
    Property [ private $passwordRepeat ] 
    Property [ private $nickname ] 
    Property [ private $permission ] 
} 
- Methods [20] {
    Method [ public method setUsername ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 15 - 17 
- Parameters [1] { 
    Parameter #0 [ $username ] 
} 
} Method [ public method setEmail ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 19 - 21 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $email ] 
} 
} Method [ public method setPassword ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 23 - 28 
- Parameters [2] { 
    Parameter #0 [ $password ] 
    Parameter #1 [ $passwordRepeat ] 
}
} Method [ public method setNickname ] { 
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 30 - 32 
- Parameters [1] { 
    Parameter #0 [ $nickname ] 
} 
} Method [ public method setPermission ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 34 - 36 
- Parameters [1] { 
    Parameter #0 [ $permission ] 
} 
} Method [ public method checkUsername ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 38 - 49 
- Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ $username ] 
    Parameter #1 [ $email ] 
} 
} Method [ public method insert ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 51 - 64
} Method [ public method update ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Users.php 66 - 75 - Parameters [1] {
Parameter #0 [ $id ] 
} 
} Method [ public method find ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Crud.php 12 - 18 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $id ] 
} 
} Method [ public method findAll ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Crud.php 20 - 26 
} Method [ public method delete ] { 
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Crud.php 28 - 33 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $id ] 
} 
} /** * Create a new DB object for the specified database type but don't * connect to the database * * @param string $type the database type (eg "mysql") * @param array $options an associative array of option names and values * * @return object a new DB object. A DB_Error object on failure. * * @see DB_common::setOption() */ 
Method [ public method &factory ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 447 - 480 
- Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ $type ] 
    Parameter #1 [ $options = false ] 
} 
} /** * Create a new DB object including a connection to the specified database * * Example 1. * * require_once 'DB.php'; * * $dsn = 'pgsql://user:password@host/database'; * $options = array( * 'debug' => 2, * 'portability' => DB_PORTABILITY_ALL, * ); * * $db =& DB::connect($dsn, $options); * if (PEAR::isError($db)) { * die($db->getMessage()); * } * * * @param mixed $dsn the string "data source name" or array in the * format returned by DB::parseDSN() * @param array $options an associative array of option names and values * * @return object a new DB object. A DB_Error object on failure. * * @uses DB_dbase::connect(), DB_fbsql::connect(), DB_ibase::connect(), * DB_ifx::connect(), DB_msql::connect(), DB_mssql::connect(), * DB_mysql::connect(), DB_mysqli::connect(), DB_oci8::connect(), * DB_odbc::connect(), DB_pgsql::connect(), DB_sqlite::connect(), * DB_sybase::connect() * * @uses DB::parseDSN(), DB_common::setOption(), PEAR::isError() */ 
Method [ public method &connect ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 518 - 567 
- Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ $dsn ] 
    Parameter #1 [ $options = Array ] 
} 
} /** * Return the DB API version * * @return string the DB API version number */ 
Method [ public method apiVersion ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 577 - 580 
} /** * Determines if a variable is a DB_Error object * * @param mixed $value the variable to check * * @return bool whether $value is DB_Error object */

Method [ public method isError ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 592 - 595 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $value ] 
} 
} /** * Determines if a value is a DB_ object * * @param mixed $value the value to test * * @return bool whether $value is a DB_ object */ 
Method [ public method isConnection ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 607 - 612 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $value ] 
} 
} /** * Tell whether a query is a data manipulation or data definition query * * Examples of data manipulation queries are INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. * Examples of data definition queries are CREATE, DROP, ALTER, GRANT, * REVOKE. * * @param string $query the query * * @return boolean whether $query is a data manipulation query */ 
Method [ public method isManip ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 628 - 639 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $query ] 
} 
} /** * Return a textual error message for a DB error code * * @param integer $value the DB error code * * @return string the error message or false if the error code was * not recognized */ 
Method [ public method errorMessage ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 652 - 694 
- Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [ $value ] 
} 
} /** * Parse a data source name * * Additional keys can be added by appending a URI query string to the * end of the DSN. * * The format of the supplied DSN is in its fullest form: * * phptype(dbsyntax)://username:password@protocol+hostspec/database?option=8&another=true * * * Most variations are allowed: * * phptype://username:password@protocol+hostspec:110//usr/db_file.db?mode=0644 * phptype://username:password@hostspec/database_name * phptype://username:password@hostspec * phptype://username@hostspec * phptype://hostspec/database * phptype://hostspec * phptype(dbsyntax) * phptype * * * @param string $dsn Data Source Name to be parsed * * @return array an associative array with the following keys: * + phptype: Database backend used in PHP (mysql, odbc etc.) * + dbsyntax: Database used with regards to SQL syntax etc. * + protocol: Communication protocol to use (tcp, unix etc.) * + hostspec: Host specification (hostname[:port]) * + database: Database to use on the DBMS server * + username: User name for login * + password: Password for login */ Method [ public method parseDSN ] { @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 733 - 850 - Parameters [1] { Parameter #0 [ $dsn ] } } /** * Returns the given DSN in a string format suitable for output. * * @param array|string the DSN to parse and format * @param boolean true to hide the password, false to include it * @return string */ 
Method [ public method getDSNString ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 862 - 926 
- Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ $dsn ] 
    Parameter #1 [ $hidePassword ] 
}}}}
```

With the  `Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass('DB'));`
I got the following response:

```
Class [ class DB ] { 
    @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php 5-30 

- Constants [0] { 
} 

- Static properties [1] { 
    Property [ private static $instance ] 
} 

- Static methods [2] { 
    Method [ static public method getInstance ] {
        @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php 9 - 24 
} 

    Method [ static public method prepare ] { 
        @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\DB.php 26 - 28 - Parameters [1] { 
            Parameter #0 [ $sql ] 
        } 
    } 
} 

- Properties [0] {
 } 

- Methods [0] { 
} }
```

So, I'm new with PHP and I'm trying to learn a little bit of PDO.
I have this code and it keeps showing this message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Crud.php on line 22

Here's my DB.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'cfg.php';

class DB{

private static $instance;

public static function getInstance(){

    if(!isset(self::$instance)){

        try {
            self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            self::$instance->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    return self::$instance;
}

public static function prepare($sql){
    return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
}

}
?>
```

Crud.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'DB.php';

abstract class Crud extends DB {

protected $table;

abstract public function insert();
abstract public function update($id);

public function find($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE ID = :id";
    $qry = DB::prepare($sql);
    $qry->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $qry->execute();
    return $qry->fetch();
}

public function findAll() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
    $qry = DB::prepare($sql);
    $qry->execute();
    return $qry->fecthAll();
}

public function delete($id) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE ID = :id";
    $qry = DB::prepare($sql);
    $qry->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    return $qry->execute();
}
}
?>
```

Then when I try to get any function from the code, I get that message.
For example, if I try that:

```
<?php

$crud = new Users();
$crud->findAll();

?>
```

Users.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'Crud.php';

class Users extends Crud {

protected $table = 'bloggy_user';
private $username;
private $email;
private $password;
private $passwordRepeat;
private $nickname;
private $permission;

public function setUsername($username) {
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email    = $email;
}

public function setPassword($password, $passwordRepeat) {
    if ($password == $passwordRepeat) {
        $cryptedPass    = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10, 'salt' => '1234567890123456789011']);
        $this->password = $cryptedPass;
    }
}

public function setNickname($nickname) {
    $this->nickname = $nickname;
}

public function setPermission($permission) {
    $this->permission = $permission;
}

public function checkUsername($username, $email) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE username = :username OR email = :email";
    $qry = DB::prepare($sql);
    $qry->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $qry->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $qry->execute();
    if ($qry->fetchColumn() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function insert() {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->table (username, email, password, nickname) VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :nickname)";
    $qry = DB::prepare($sql);
    $qry->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
    $qry->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
    $qry->bindParam(':password', $this->password);
    $qry->bindParam(':nickname', $this->nickname);
    if ($this->checkUsername($this->username, $this->email)) {
        return $qry->execute();
    } else {
        echo "Esse usuário já existe";
        return false;
    }
}

public function update($id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET email = :email, password = :password, nickname = :nickname, permission = :permission WHERE ID = :id";
    $qry = DB::prepare($sql);
    $qry->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
    $qry->bindParam(':password', $this->password);
    $qry->bindParam(':nickname', $this->nickname);
    $qry->bindParam(':permission', $this->permission);
    $qry->bindParam(':id', $id); 
    return $qry->execute();
}
}


?>
```

It does show the error message.
Idk if I made myself clear enough, but I'm really a noob at PDO, so if anyone can help me I'd be grateful.

Comment: Where the heck is the `Users` class? You're leaving out some pertinent data for us to analyze.

Comment: And why would you extend (or use...) a singleton?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll edit and Add the Users class

Comment: Can't reproduce, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/rPbe0y; it dies on the `prepare` method in the `DB` class.

Comment: But why is it dying in the prepare method?

Comment: In my test case because there is no PDO connection. However, it has passed the line where you got your error message.

Comment: I'm using a `cfg.php` file that has the constants to connect with the PDO. 
I don't understand why I'm getting that error message, it's almost the same as the tutorial and he's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I correct other mistakes (see below), the code works for me. I wonder if your require_once is finding a different file that is also named DB.php? I would test this by adding a line like `print "Hello!";` inside DB.php but outside the class definition. Then run your script and see if your printed message appears.

If the message does not appear, then your script is extending a DB class from some different file that require_once is finding before it finds your current DB.php. This sort of mistake happens all the time if you have multiple copies of the same code, and you don't manage your PHP include_path carefully.

If that works, then you must have a DB class that somehow doesn't have a `static function prepare()`. You can add this code to your script to find out what methods it thinks it has:

```
    Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass('DB'));
```

Or test the actual Crud object just before you call prepare() in your `findAll()` method:

```
    Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass($this));
```

---

Okay, I see your output from the reflection export and I notice this:

```
/** * Create a new DB object for the specified database type but don't * connect to the database * * @param string $type the database type (eg "mysql") * @param array $options an associative array of option names and values * * @return object a new DB object. A DB_Error object on failure. * * @see DB_common::setOption() */ 
Method [ public method &factory ] {
    @@ C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php 447 - 480 
- Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ $type ] 
    Parameter #1 [ $options = false ] 
}
```

Notice that `factory()` method says that it's originally defined in `C:\xampp\php\pear\DB.php`. And neither the getInstance() nor prepare() methods of your DB class are in that reflection export at all!

So your `class Crud extends DB` is actually finding the pear DB.php before it finds your own DB class.

This is why PHP supports [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), so you can make sure you have a unique identifier for your class, even if the base class name conflicts with some other class.

Or alternatively you could rename your DB class to something distinct like `myDB` or `DBconnection` or something like that.

Or you could change your `include_path` so it finds your project files before the pear files.

This also explains why the code works in my environment, because I'm not using XAMPP or anything else that installs PEAR classes.

---

Other mistakes:

- Your PDO connection might fail, for example due to getting the hostname or user/password wrong.
- Don't `catch()` exceptions if you're not going to correct the root cause or return a failure. When your connection fails in getInstance(), you echo the error, but then return the instance anyway.
- Don't call `getInstance()->prepare()` when there's a chance that `getInstance()` won't return a PDO object. Separate it into two calls, on to get the instance, and the second to call prepare() *only* if the instance is returned as a valid PDO object.

  ```
  $instance = self::getInstance();
  if ($instance instanceof PDO) {
      return $instance->prepare($sql);
  } else {
      throw new Exception("Not a PDO");
  }
  ```
- You misspelled `fetchAll()` as `fecthAll()` in your `findAll()` function.
- You call `findAll()` but you don't assign the result to a variable.
- Edit: I thought `"$this->table"` would not work, but it turns out I was incorrect, it does work. But you may still need to know about using curly braces around variables inside strings for other kinds of expressions, like picking array elements.

Comment: Very good points, but I still can't see how the OP can get the error message mentioned :-)

Comment: Did the changes about the misspelled words and the queries. But I'm still getting that error message. I've even changed the PDO connection so I'm not using constants anymore and nothing changed...

Comment: Added the `print "Hello";` inside the `DB.php` and it still won't work. (It shows `Hello` on the screen) How do I separate `getInstance()->prepare()` in two calls?

Comment: @LucasPadilha, thanks for doing that test. It's always worth double-checking. I added another suggestion above.

Comment: Changed `DB::prepare()` to `$this->prepare()` and it only changed from `Call to undefined method DB::prepare()` to `Call to undefined method Users::prepare()`. I don't know what to do! That's insane, the tutorial works 100%.

Comment: This is indeed puzzling.  Okay, next I'd try `Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass($this));` as the first line inside the `Crud::findAll()` function.

Comment: Thanks man... My issue fixed when use a different name I think problem with name 'db' I  changed to database now it works.